# where_not_in not return match by array value as param

Tags: codeigniter

trying to get `TraineeID` where `$arrTID` not in `tbl_attendance_processed` but my code below return all `TraineeID` from `tbl_attendance_processed`.

If I use `where_in` then the query return absolute result those `TraineeID` are really matched. Just not returning appropriate when I use `where_not_in`.

Model:

```
public function getNotMatch_TID($arrTID,$atnDate){
        $this->db->select('TraineeID');
        $this->db->where_not_in('TraineeID', $arrTID);
        $this->db->where('attnDate', $atnDate);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_attendance_processed');

        return $query->result();
    }
```

controller:

```
$arrTID = $this->input->post('Present');
$atnDate = $this->input->post('attnDate'); 
$nonMatch= $this->AttendanceModel->getNotMatch_TID($arrTID,$atnDate);
print_r($nonMatch);
```

echo last query:

[image]

table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attendance_processed` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `TraineeID` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `attnDate` date NOT NULL,
 `inTime` time NOT NULL,
 `outTime` time NOT NULL,
 `Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `ClassCount` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `Reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3186 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: `$arrTID` should be an array

Comment: of course it is an array, the query return with this `$arrTID` when I used `where_in` in my query.

Comment: Print your query `echo $this->db->last_query()` and please post

Comment: sir, I added the last query

Comment: What datatype for TraineeID field ? and directly run this last query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: data type `varchar`. And when I directly run this last query in phpmyadmin then return the same result not accurate.

Comment: then something wrong with your query. Need to explain what you want